# Hibernate - same class with different tables

Tags: java, mysql, sql, hibernate

I'm trying to build an app that uses a table for each user.
Each user's table should contain about 10K lines, so I don't want one big table with all the information' I prefer to divide it to small tables.

Here is an example:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Items")
public class item{
   @Id @GeneratedValue
   @Column(name = "id")
   private int id;

   @Column(name = "Description")
   private String description;
...
```

Can I somehow make multiple tables that use that same class and will look like this? :

Items_user1

Items_user2

...

Comment: Do not hesitate for 10K lines (or 10M lines) per table. That is what RDBMS is all about.

Comment: This table will contain about 1.5M rows, I'm afraid queries will take a long time.

Comment: Don't worry about that, it's what databases exist for.  1.5M isn't a lot of rows and dividing data into 10K chunks is strange!

Comment: Thanks! I will test it.